# Using Firebase and/or filters in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to make an app where the users can search for other users via text, and I'm running into an exception every time I try querying with the filters. I currently need to query two fields to check if they contain a substring. These have the names `"name"` and `"uname"`. So this is the solution I came up with:

```
usersRef = usersRef.where(Filter.or(
      Filter.and(Filter('name', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: queryText),
          Filter('name', isLessThanOrEqualTo: '$queryText\uf8ff')),
      Filter.and(Filter('uname', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: queryText),
          Filter('uname', isLessThanOrEqualTo: '$queryText\uf8ff')),
    ));
```

Unfortunately, using `.get()` on `usersRef` this code gives me the error

> FirebaseException ([cloud_firestore/invalid-argument] Client specified an invalid argument. Note that this differs from failed-precondition. invalid-argument indicates arguments that are problematic regardless of the state of the system (e.g., an invalid field name).)

From web searches, it seems like this exception could mean a number of things, so I'm hoping someone who has gone through what I have before can point out what I'm doing wrong.. I also tried:

```
        usersRef = usersRef.where(['displayName', 'username'],
        isGreaterThanOrEqualTo:
            queryText).where(['displayName', 'username'],
        isLessThanOrEqualTo: '$queryText\uf8ff');
```

And that gives me the exception:

> Exception has occurred.
> _AssertionError ('package:cloud_firestore/src/query.dart': Failed assertion: line 315 pos 7: 'field is String ||
> field is FieldPath ||
> field == FieldPath.documentId ||
> field is Filter': Supported [field] types are [String], [FieldPath], and [Filter].)

Of course I could do separate queries, but the idea is to minimize the amount of times I make a request to the database. *Thanks to everyone in advance!*

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation on [query limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations) you'll see:

> In a compound query, range (<, <=, >, >=) and not equals (!=, not-in) comparisons must all filter on the same field.

---

In your code sample you add range conditions on two fields, so that isn't allowed.

---

In your second example, you are trying to pass an array for the field name, which also isn't possible.

---

As the documentation on query limitations says: you can only have a range condition on a single field in a Firestore query. There is no workaround for that limitation, so if that's a hard requirement for your use-case, you'll want to look at using another database.